# Fill columns with formulas in a loop

Tags: excel, vba

how can I fill the entire row (or to given column) with formulas that will use values from same column but different rows in VBA? That is I want to fill a range lets say from column `B` to column `D` at row `6` with formulas:
`=SUM(B4:B5)`, `=SUM(C4:C5)`, `=SUM(D4:D5)`
Because my number of columns will varry I can't make it static
If it was row wise not column wise I would do:

```
For row = 1 To 10
   ActiveSheet.Range("B" & row).Formula =  "=SUM(C" & row & "D" & row & ")"
Next row
```

but I don't know how can I do that by changing column (letter).
I was thinking about making an array filled with letters as

```
myColumns = Array("A", "B", ..., "ZZ")
```

and then loop through it, but writing such long array might be kind of pathetic :v

Comment: Are "R1C1" formulae a possible answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a loop for this. Try:

```
Sub fill_formula()

With Range("B6:J6")
    .Formula = "=SUM(B4:B5)"
End With

End Sub
```

This will populate `B6` with `=SUM(B4:B5)`, `C6` with `=SUM(C4:C5)` and so on through to column `J`. This works because the cell references are relative (e.g. `B4`, not `$B$4`).

If you really want a loop, try using [`Worksheet.Cells`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.cells) with [`Range.Address`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.address).

```
Sub fill_formula_loop()

For col = 2 To 10
    address_start = ActiveSheet.Cells(4, col).Address(False, False)
    address_end = ActiveSheet.Cells(5, col).Address(False, False)
    
    ActiveSheet.Cells(6, col).Formula = "=SUM(" & address_start & ":" & address_end & ")"
Next col

End Sub
```